# Showing Exceptions when i send request to server using post method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

Hi i am very new for Ios and in my project i am sending "POST" request to server ok that's fine

Here i want to send key2 value through NSString like using below "First Formate" but using that above formate it's showing exception like('-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b7f2a50')

When i send response to server using  "Second Formate" i am not getting exceptions i am getting responce from services please help me where did i do wrong in  "First Formate"

```
 First Formate:-
     ---------------

     NSString * mainStringvalue = [IdArray objectAtIndex:12];

     NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"COLLECTION",@"key1",
                                mainStringvalue,@"key2" ,
                                nil];

     Second Formate:-
     ----------------

      NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"COLLECTION",@"key1",
                                @"15",@"key2" ,
                                nil];
```

Comment: What does your IdArray contains?

Comment: my idArray contains integer values(like 10,15,100)

Comment: So does it have plain integers? or they are wrapped in NSNumber?

Comment: you need to convert integer to string.

Comment: plain integers not wrapped NSNumers

Comment: So you needs to convert it in NSString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your contains NSNumber object. You first need to convert them into NSString.

Try below:

```
NSString * mainStringvalue = [[IdArray objectAtIndex:12] stringValue];

NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"COLLECTION",@"key1",
                                mainStringvalue,@"key2" ,
                                nil];
```

Comment: If it worked well, then you should accept the answer.